# how to plot this circular graph that represent up and down value?

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, draw, bioinformatics

[image: circular grap]

I have one list that represent gene expression value, and the data has high expression and low expression relatively. I want to plot this circular graph that highly expressed outside the circle and lowly expressed inside the circle. So I would like to ask what program can achieve this picture. It would be best if an example can be given.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Using `ggplot`, this can be accomplished with `geom_ribbon` and `coord_polar`, it would look something like this:

```
ggplot(gene_data) + coord_polar() +
    geom_ribbon(aes(ymin=low_exp,
    ymax=high_exp
    x=seq_num))
```

A common example of this has `x = day_of_the_year` and `y = something_measured_that_day`

Comment: Thank you very much for help, I did as you said and plot a figure that added to the original question. But I still can't get that effect. The obvious problem is how can I enlarge that circle and keep those data on the outermost circle. There are about 160 data in this circle, they huddled together. how can I keep them on the outer circle to spread them apart, just like the first picture? thank you very much

Comment: You're welcome. Could you please provide the ggplot code you used to generate the above plot?